# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression (powershell, sharepoint)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I created a powershell script with the purpose of reading a text document and applying changes to a field in a sharepoint environment. Sorry for any errors in technical jargon im just starting out and still learning. Heres the script:

```
  $data = Get-Content "e:\projects.txt"
  write-host $data.count total lines read from file
  foreach ($line in $data)
  {
  write-host $line
  $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://bizprojectsqa.westerncape.gov.za/PWA/"
  $list = $web.GetList($line)
  $query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>(2)Active</Value></Eq></Where>"    
  $view = $list.Views["All Active Risks"]
  $view.Query = $query
  $view.Update();

 }
```

Heres the error message:

```
 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
 At C:\temp\pwa_risks.ps1:12 char:13
 +$view.Update <<<< ();
+CategoryInfo         : InvalidOperation: (Update:String) [], RuntimeException
 +FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodNull
```

I think it has something to do with $view.Update() but im not 100% sure.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the error message:

Comment: Hi, you can edit your question to add it.

Comment: Does this happen for a specific line or all of them? Only thing I know for sure is that at the time error occurs `$view` is null.